# IIS 7.5 + Windows Server 2008 R2 + ASP.NET 4.0 HTTP 500 Error?

Tags: iis, asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm having an issue I cannot track down and I have looked through the forums and not found anything that sheds any light.  I have a fresh install of a Server 2008 R2 Web that I am trying to load an application I created and tested on a Windows 7 machine running IIS 7.5 using ASP.NET 4.0.  Everything works fine on the dev machine.  But when I used the Web Deployment tool to move it to the server, I now get a HTTP 500 error without a lot of information:

```
Module AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule
Notification BeginRequest
Handler StaticFile
Error Code 0x80070002
Requested URL http://192.168.1.83:80/
Physical Path C:\JustStreamIt
Logon Method Not yet determined
Logon User Not yet determined
Failed Request Tracing Log Directory C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles
```

And in my trace file I get:

96. view trace Warning -SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_DESCRIPTION
    ErrorDescription An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
97. view trace Warning -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
    ModuleName AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule
    Notification 1
    HttpStatus 500
    HttpReason Internal Server Error
    HttpSubStatus 0
    ErrorCode 2147942402
    ConfigExceptionInfo
    Notification BEGIN_REQUEST
    ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)

And I get the following in the Application Log:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP
Date:          5/28/2010 2:08:10 PM
Event ID:      2299
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      win-ltfkdo1dnfp
Description: 
An application has reported as being unhealthy. The worker process will now request a recycle. Reason given: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
. The data is the error.

```
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP" Guid="{670080D9-742A-4187-8D16-41143D1290BD}" EventSourceName="W3SVC-WP" />
<EventID Qualifiers="49152">2299</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-05-28T21:08:10.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>1663</EventRecordID>
<Correlation />
<Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>win-ltfkdo1dnfp</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
    <Data Name="Reason">An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
</Data>
<Binary>02000780</Binary>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Anyone have a suggestion about where I should start looking?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the application event log for the server?

Comment: Does your newly installed Windows Server 2008 R2 has .net 4.0 installed as well?

Comment: The response from the application log is above. I actually gave up and went with Server 2008 (not R2) and it works like a champ.  Zero issues.